# How to animate widget on a circumference of a circle?

Tags: flutter

I have a page, and the page has some cool shapes on the background. I want them to move around.

I've put those orange circles as an example. I want those purple shapes to float on the orange circles' circumference.

> Note: Orange circles are examples to show where each object(purple
> ones) can float around. I don't want to put orange circles or draw anything on the screen. Question about moving shapes around.
>
> I've already did displaying part with a simple `Container` and `SVG`.

[image]

Comment: @pskink How does CustomPaint help with floating these objects on an invisible circle's circumference?

Comment: because it is the most efficient way of doing animations like your case (without rebuilding all the stuff each frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo:**

[image]

**Solution:**

Create a Tween between 0 and 360, get `Offset` for each value and positioned it in `Stack` with `Positioned`. Using Offset's x and y values.

```
  final _tween = IntTween(begin: 0, end: 360);
  late Animation<int> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 20))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
    _animation = _tween.animate(_controller);

    _controller.repeat();

    super.initState();
  }

  Offset _getOffset(int angle, int distance) {
    return Offset.fromDirection(math.pi / 180 * angle, distance.toDouble());
  }
```

And in the `Stack`

```
Positioned(
  top: _getOffset(_animation.value, 200).dy + 200,
  left: _getOffset(_animation.value, 200).dx + 200,
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    UI.purpleTriangle,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
   ),
 ),
```

I've used only one animation controller, but `distance` I give to `getOffset` and the +200 for Positioned was enough to randomize those invisible circles.

Comment: @pskink try reading the original question again. there's one more sentence before the one you've quoted.